# Ruby: How Extracting Words From String

Tags: ruby, regex

I want get words from string.
For example:
`str = "Mike's book."`.
I wish I can get `["Mike's", "book"]`.

I know we can `str.split(/\W+/)`, but it will return `["Mike", "s", "book"]`, that's not what I want.

Comment: `str.split('\s+')` ?

Comment: why not google it?

Comment: Thx, but it has "." I should give more example.

Comment: Replace the `.` or other undesired characters with empty space before splitting.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`scan()`](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/scan) method in Ruby with [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) regex including word character and single quote.

```
str.scan(/[\w']+/)
```

Comment: Thanks. it works. For ruby we can use `str.scan(/[\w']+/)`